# compare arbitrary shapes using generalized hough transform

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, hough-transform

I am using generalized hough transform to differentiate between various arbitrary shapes. Few shapes that I'll be dealing with is shown below:
http://i50.tinypic.com/2u550t5.png

I have implemented the following steps successfully:

**A) Transform / Training phase**

**i)** Threshold to get binary image
**ii)** Get contour using cvFindContour
**iii)** calculate distance 'r' and gradient orientation (phi) for each edge pixel
**iv)** Create R-table

Create a database of R-table for each shape

**B) Recognition**

**i)** Get contour of an arbitrary shape
**ii)** calculate gradient orientation for each edge pixel
**iii)** Using R-table, build the accumulator

My problem is how do I proceed further?

How do I detect the shape using this accumulator data?

Comment: Maybe you can ask to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In order to detect the shapes you have to find peaks (maximum) in the accumulator image.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, once you have the accumulator image, you have to find the peaks in it, i.e., the pixel (or cells) with the highest number of "votes", a peak should represent, roughly speaking, the location of your shape.

There are a lot of tutorials about the Generalized Hough Tutorial, I like the one contained in the thesis ["Hierarchical Real-Time Recognition of Compound Objects in Images"](http://tumb1.biblio.tu-muenchen.de/publ/diss/bv/2003/ulrich.pdf) by M. Ulrich where the figures 4.3, 4.4 and 4.5 clearly explain the subject.